# SCOPE_IDENTITY returning null values sometimes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a SQL query where sometimes the `IDENTITY` value from the `INSERT [Form]` in the first statement comes back as `NULL` and causes the rest of the statements in the batch to fail.

I included the second block of the procedure to indicate where it fails due to a conflict with the `FK` constraint on the table `Form`

Previously, it had been using `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, but I had changed it to use SQL Server's temp tables and an `OUTPUT` clause to see if it would alleviate the issue and it hasn't.

This procedure is being called from an ASP.NET webforms application, and the call is initiated by a Web API call running in that application.

Previously before this was ever made into a Web API call, it was initiated by a click event in the webforms application. Back then I would see this error occur every now and again.

With more and more use of the application and heavier loads, this seems to occur more frequently.

I checked and there are no triggers on the table that are firing off. I can't think of any way to replicate or track down the problem.

In most cases the procedure works fine, but every now and again it doesn't, and I'm unsure why. Sometimes I'll see a log of the error occurring multiple times in a row as the user attempts to save what they are working on. If they try enough times, it seems to work.

I've looked into using other forms of identity retrieval like `@@IDENTITY` and those won't work for what I need.

Is there something I'm missing?

`````
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IC_Note_UpdateForm]
    @FormID int = -1 OUTPUT, @ConsultFormID int = -1 OUTPUT, @PatientSignature bit, @DSPSignature bit, @Editable bit, @Narrative nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, @SignificantIssues nvarchar(MAX), @UserID int, @DSPID int, @FormTypeID int, @ServiceID int, @ApptID int OUTPUT, @LocationID int, @LoggedInUser int, @PortalId int,@ClientNotes nvarchar(MAX)
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--This is needed for whatever reason in order to get the correct date submitted. Using the function call inline causes weird stuff to happen 
DECLARE @DateSubmitted DATETIME = dbo.GetLocalTime(default)

DECLARE @count int
--See if a record exists for the Form
SELECT @count = COUNT(FormId) FROM Form WHERE (formID = @FormID OR (apptID = @ApptID AND apptID >= 1))

if @count > 0 BEGIN

    UPDATE dbo.Form SET 
        FormTypeID = @FormTypeID,
        patientSignature = @PatientSignature,
        dspSignature = @DSPSignature,
        editable = @Editable,
        dateSubmitted = @DateSubmitted
    WHERE 
        formID = @FormID

    IF @Editable = 0 BEGIN
        exec IC_NoteAudit_Insert @FormId, @DSPID, 'SUBMITTED'
    END ELSE BEGIN 
        exec IC_NoteAudit_Insert @FormID, @DSPID, 'UPDATED'
    END

END ELSE BEGIN
    DECLARE @tempForm TABLE (FormId int) 

    INSERT dbo.Form (
        PortalId
        ,userID
        ,dspID
        ,dateSubmitted
        ,patientSignature
        ,dspSignature
        ,editable
        ,approved
        ,dateApproved
        ,rejected
        ,formTypeID
        ,paid
        ,billed
        ,serviceID
        ,apptID
    ) OUTPUT inserted.formId INTO @tempForm
        VALUES (
            @PortalId
        ,@UserID   -- userID - int
        ,@DSPID   -- dspID - int
        ,@DateSubmitted  -- dateSubmitted - datetime
        ,@PatientSignature  -- patientSignature - bit
        ,@DSPSignature  -- dspSignature - bit
        ,@Editable  -- editable - bit
        ,null  -- approved - bit
        ,null  -- dateApproved - datetime
        ,null  -- rejected - bit
        ,@FormTypeID   -- formTypeID - int
        ,0  -- paid - bit
        ,0  -- billed - bit
        ,@ServiceID   -- serviceID - int
        ,@ApptID   -- apptID - int
    )

    --This was SET @FormId = SCOPE_IDENTITY() before and had the same NULL FK constraint occur 
    SET @FormID = (SELECT TOP 1 FormId FROM @tempForm)

END

--Move these out of scope of the IDENTITY retrieval 
IF @count = 0 BEGIN 
    exec IC_NoteAudit_Insert @formID, @DSPID, 'CREATED'

    IF @Editable = 0 BEGIN
        exec IC_NoteAudit_Insert @formID, @DSPID, 'SUBMITTED'
    END
END

SELECT @count = COUNT(FormId) FROM ConsultForm WHERE formId = @FormID
IF @count > 0 BEGIN

--See if a row exists for the ConsultForm
UPDATE dbo.ConsultForm SET 
    narrative = @Narrative,
    significantIssues = @SignificantIssues
WHERE 
    consultFormID = @ConsultFormID
    AND formID = @FormID

END ELSE BEGIN
    DECLARE @tempConsultForm TABLE (ConsultFormId int)
    INSERT dbo.ConsultForm (
        PortalId
        ,formID
        ,dateOfService
        ,timeIn
        ,timeOut
        ,narrative
        ,significantIssues
        ,locationOfService
    ) OUTPUT inserted.ConsultFormID INTO @tempConsultForm
    VALUES (
        @PortalId,
        @FormID    -- formID - int
        ,null  -- dateOfService - datetime
        ,null  -- timeIn - datetime
        ,null  -- timeOut - datetime
        ,@Narrative -- narrative - nvarchar(MAX)
        ,@SignificantIssues -- significantIssues - nvarchar(MAX)
        ,null -- locationOfService - nvarchar(MAX)
    )

    /*** Failure with FK constraint happens here, @FormId is NULL ***/

    SET @ConsultFormID = (SELECT TOP 1 ConsultFormId FROM @tempConsultForm)

END ````
`````

Comment: Does the Form table have an identity column? Something is a bit off here but I can't quite see what it is.

Comment: @SeanLange sure does! It has a lot of records too, about 160,000+

Answer (score 0):

Which Version of SQL, seems like a bug in SQL. Can You use RAISERROR inside the SQL Code to make sure whether it is an issue in SQL itself.

Comment: Assuming it's latest as this database is running in Azure. The error comes down as a SqlException in the ASP.NET code so it has to be generated by the procedure otherwise it wouldn't throw a SqlException.